# How do I set package-vc-selected-packages to use a specific commit?

Tags: package, git, customize, variables, package-repositories

Emacs 29.1 introduced new functions to install packages directly from source.

Configuring it to download from the latest commit works fine, but I can't find how to download from a specific commit instead.

Here is an example:

```
(setopt package-vc-selected-packages
        '((magit :url "https://github.com/magit/magit"
                 :tag 95d5be9)
          (yasnippet :url "https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet")))
```

then do `M-x package-vc-install-selected-packages`

In this example yasnippet gets downloaded from the latest commit, which is fine, but Magit can't be downloaded at all if I specify a particular commit hash.

I tried using :tag, :rev, quoted the string but nothing seems to work.

Is it even possible to do this? Or am I confused by the documentation?